# RegExp Extract text from a template

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a question about regular expression and javascript. The user will have a input with the following template as text (it will change according to the user's selection) as example:

```
Accessories <accessory type> for a Group, for <What Purpose>
```

Now the user will modify the input text and let's say it end up like this.

Accessories of *my printer* for a Group, for *my computer*

I want to see if i can extract from that text the values for  if that case it will be 'my computer'. There will be case where i modify completely the text, but i can take out of the equation for now.

Can it be done with a regular expression? or is there something or lib to help me with this?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: You mean like [this](https://regex101.com/r/lP3iX0/1) ?

Comment: Does this help you? [`/^Accessories\sof\s+(.*)\s+for\sa\sGroup,\sfor\s+(.*)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/kR5dD5/1)

Comment: If you know what words comes before and after, you can just split the string on that.

Comment: i'm building it, i will post the response tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = 'Accessories <accessory type> for a Group, for <What Purpose>';
var result = text;

var params =
{
        '<accessory type>': 'of my printer',
        '<What Purpose>': 'my computer'
};

var m = text.match(/<[^>]+>/g);

for(var i in m)
{
        var re = new RegExp(m[i], 'g');
        result = result.replace(re, params[m[i]]);
}

console.log(result);
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/ka4965uh/

RESULT:
Accessories of my printer for a Group, for my computer

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```
^Accessories\s+(?:of\s)?(.*?)\s+for\sa\sGroup,\sfor\s+(.*)\s*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regex will do the following:

- capture the `accessories` value
- ignore the substring `of` preceding the `accessories` value
- capture the `for` substring value
- remove any white space surrounding either captured values

**Capture Groups**

- Capture group 0 gets the entire string
- Capture group 1 gets the `accessories` value
- Capture group 2 gets the `for` value

## Example

**Live demo**

https://regex101.com/r/dB0aK5/1

**Sample Text**

```
Accessories <accessory type> for a Group, for <What Purpose>
Accessories of my printer for a Group, for my computer
```

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][0] = Accessories <accessory type> for a Group, for <What Purpose>
[0][1] = <accessory type>
[0][2] = <What Purpose>

[1][0] = Accessories of my printer for a Group, for my computer
[1][1] = my printer
[1][2] = my computer
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Accessories              'Accessories'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    of                       'of'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  for                      'for'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  a                        'a'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Group,                   'Group,'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  for                      'for'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```